# Monitor does not display the correct service status

Tags: monit

I use monit V5.25.3 with a poll interval of 30 seconds. Monit is used for 50 services including the apache server. The apache server can be activated or inactive. When the apache server is inactive, after (configuration change) and commands: "monit reload" and "monit start all" monit is "busy" for 24-25 seconds(see the listing below) with apache. All services that are processed after this have the status "start pending" and after 30 seconds remain in the previous state.

Is there a way to prevent this blockage or is this an error in the monitor?

```
Sep 24 08:27:33 falcon root: Starting OpenVPN (if configured)
Sep 24 08:27:33 falcon monit[9435]: pidfile '/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid' does not exist
Sep 24 08:27:33 falcon monit[9435]: pidfile '/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid' does not exist
...
...
Sep 24 08:27:57 falcon monit[9435]: pidfile '/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid' does not exist
Sep 24 08:27:57 falcon monit[9435]: 'webdav' test skipped as required service 'webdav_config' is not monitored 
Sep 24 08:27:57 falcon monit[9435]: Reinitializing Monit -- control file '/etc/monitrc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experiences based monit 5.26.0 (and newer) it is more useful to wait until the end of the check services interval.
The status should fit after the check, on the other hand, you can use "monit validate" to force a check.

New services, became available with a "monit reload", will be started as long as you set the proper start mode, see https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SYSTEM-REBOOT-AND-SERVICE-STARTUP

But sometimes, the services the new services depend to, must started first.
The right status will be available at the end of the second/third interval
after the reload.